# Angular custom filter with multiple dropdown conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter with multiple dropdowns conditions. I am able to figure out how to filter them one by one. I want them to show all when nothing is chosen, value = "".

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.grade">
  <option ng-repeat="grade in product_grades" value="{{grade}}">{{grade}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.slump">
  <option ng-repeat="slump in product_slumps" value="{{slump}}">{{slump}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.flow">
  <option ng-repeat="flow in product_flows" value="{{flow}}">{{flow}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="filter.last_delivered">
  <option ng-repeat="last_delivered in product_last_delivereds" value="{{last_delivered}}">{{displayDate(last_delivered)}}</option>
</select>

<tr ng-repeat="job_product in job_products | filter : customFilter">
```

For one drop down, I use this.

```
$scope.customFilter = function (data) {
    if (data.Grade === $scope.filter.grade) {
      return true;
    } else if ($scope.filter.grade === '') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

But when I use this for multiple dropdowns, it works.

```
$scope.customFilter = function (data) {
    if (data.Grade === $scope.filter.grade && 
      data.Slump === $scope.filter.slump && 
      data.Flow === $scope.filter.flow && 
      data.LastDlvDate === $scope.filter.last_delivered) {
      return true;
    } else if ($scope.filter.grade === '') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

When I choose a drop option now it doesn't show anything.

Here's a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/elwmuqLvhYhIw3rUrEO1?p=preview

I am not sure why $filter for the date is not working.

But I want to show concrete A when choosing grade = "1".

Comment: try starting with replacing `ng-repeat` with `ng-options` and see if that makes the task easier.

Comment: i'm not too sure how to get it to work

Comment: can you provide a complete example with some sample data?

Comment: Claies I added a plunker

Comment: sorry i think i asked the question incorrectly at first, i edited the question now, hope it makes more sense with the plunker example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example - http://plnkr.co/edit/VTnbqchrdsrN5w0mflji?p=preview

What was wrong?

- The `$scope.customFilter` conditionals were wrong - `data.grade === $scope.filter.grade`. The default value for each `$scope.filter.*` was empty string `''` and because you used `&&` them all together, while `data.grade` was selected, the others were `'' === undefined` which ends up being `false`. So I changed the conditionals to `!$scope.filter.grade || data.grade === $scope.filter.grade && ...`. This works because I check if the select has not changed at all, I ignore it by returning `true` and then if the selected one equals to the `data`. That also made `} else if ($scope.filter.grade === '') {` irrelevant.

Additional notes on the implementation:

- You do not have to initialize the scope variables `$scope.filter.grade = "";`, Angular will on first select change.
- Fixed the date filter part, the `$scope.displayDate` is not needed. You can apply the filter in template `{{last_delivered | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}`

Comment: for the last delivered, it works in your plunker but for some reason in my code, it gets the value of {{last_delivered}} gets converted to a different timezone and it's not working - "2015-11-18T16:00:00.000Z" , any ideas

Comment: Maybe because your ``$scope.last_delivered`` is supposed to be ``$scope.product_last_delivereds`` array of all possible dates.